# Dependency Hierarchy view (Maven) fails when processing the project POM file

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.7.3, which is a customized flavour of the Eclipse IDE.  We are developing a family of micro-services, broken into individual Spring Boot projects, using Maven as the dependency management tool of choice.

Recently I lost the ability to use the "Dependency Hierarchy" view to navigate and inspect the list of dependencies associated with each of the projects.  It builds this from the pom.xml file, which appears to be correctly formed.

Although I can explore the pom.xml file, and view the Overview, Dependencies, and Effective Pom sections, the Dependency Hierarchy view fails every time.

A "Problem Occurred" dialogue box appears with the message:
 **"Loading pom.xml has encountered a problem.  An internal error occurred during 'Loading pom.xml'**

Although not critical, I would appreciate having access to this tool.

- I suspect that either an Eclipse/Maven plugin has become corrupted, or that there is a configuration issue buried somewhere, perhaps within the POM file itself.
- I pulled down all updates to Eclipse, and they installed without errors.  Spring Tool Suite is fully up-to-date, as are the associated Eclipse plugin's.
- After a full restart of Spring Tool Suite, I was able to briefly see a list of dependencies populate.  After a moment, the original error returned and blanked out the list.

If you have encountered this issue, and know how I might attempt to resolve it,  I’d love to hear what worked for you.  Some of these issues have simple causes, when you know where to look.  :-)

Comment: To check that the pom is fine just try to build on plain command line...BTW: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using Maven 3.5.2.  Thank you for your suggestion.  I had tried rebuilding my project previously, and it built without errors.  I'll run it again to see if there are any warnings or other messages that could lend a clue to what is happening.

Comment: To be honest I had issues with Eclipse as well. What helped was to remove the whole workspace and create a new from scratch..